# How protect a route with a Laravel SSR project and a Laravel API project

Tags: angular, laravel, vue.js, jwt

I have a simple Laravel project and a Laravel API project.

I use both because I use a mobile app that consumes this API and I need a central API application.

So when I authenticate to a simple website I can use Authentication core from Laravel but if I use API to make the authentication how I will protect a route page like a user page?

Because of my Laravel SSR, I use blade + vue.js for simple components and they use some protected requests by token that I store in the cookie.

How can I make an authentication user that my Laravel knows the logged user and my vue.js component too?

My doubt is simple:

**How I can authenticate a simple Laravel project if the simple Laravel is not the main project to make the authentication is a Laravel API project that uses token, how is the process?**

Comment: dose this article help, https://medium.com/employbl/build-authentication-into-your-laravel-api-with-json-web-tokens-jwt-cd223ace8d1a